# Defining style per tags in Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tags, themes, tumblr

I would like to know how to define the specific style for specific tags. For instance, I would like to have my posts render a certain style if they're tagged with Croissant or Chocolate.

I think know I have to create a new class and I know I have to style this new class but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use `{TagsAsClasses}` in your theme.

For example, you'll need to write something like for your theme:

```
<div id="{PostID}" class="post {PostType} {TagsAsClasses}">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

If your post is a photo post and has the tags Croissant and Chocolate, then your HTML becomes:

```
<div id="post-26107509778" class="post photo Croissant Chocolate">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

and then you can set the styles for the .Croissant or .Chocolate classes:

```
.Croissant {
  /* add your styles here */
}

.Chocolate {
  /* add your styles here */
}
```

More info here http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's clearer now. Whereabouts should I put the code in the whole thing?

I think I must define something within these div tags. Or not?

Comment: Yes, the post contents. If you are just editing an existing HTML theme, you should start by looking inside `{block:Posts}` - you already have the post elements there, you just need to add the class. Be careful - you may need to add it several times, as different post types may be defined separately. See this section http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#get_started As for the CSS, you put it as your custom CSS.