# Different style per tagged page on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to change the style of a tagged *page* on Tumblr (as in the page that collects all the specific tags - for [example](http://tinyurl.com/kanfrjx)). At the moment all the tagged pages look the same. This is the code I've used -

```
{block:TagPage}
<div id="sp">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1 class="main-logo"><a href="/">
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/p5cn7shd5/logo_web.png" alt="" />
</a></h1>
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /portrwrap -->
{/block:TagPage}
```

[Working example](http://tinyurl.com/kanfrjx)

I'm trying to use a different background for a certain tagged page. For example, when you visit the /tagged/shows page, it has a different background to the /tagged/news page.

Unlike Wordpress, I've been unable to find a page ID. I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523662/defining-style-per-tags-in-tumblr) but that only changes the style of the post, not the tagged page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set an '#id' on the body element, based on the current tag:

```
<body {block:TagPage}id="{URLSafeTag}"{/block:TagPage} />
...
</body>
```

When you visit a tagged page, `tagged/news/` the HTML will render like so:

```
<body id="news" />
...
</body>
```

That way you can change all elements on the page, such as the navigation.

```
#news #nav {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Reference: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tag-pages

Comment: Great! Thank you! Curious... how do I change the other elements on the page without it interfering with the other pages? For example, the navigation background

Comment: @SocialMonster Updated the answer with an example.